# Read and Write a String in/from Stream without Helper Classes

Tags: c#, vb.net

Lets say I wanna write a string `"Hello World"` into a `MemoryStream` and read this string to `MessageBox.Show()` without using Helper objects such as `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` and `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` etc.

Can you show me how to accomplish this with low-level functions of `MemoryStream` stream object.

P.s: I both use C# and VB.NET so, please feel free to use either of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to choose a text encoding and use it to grab the data:

```
        var data = "hello, world";

        // Encode the string (I've chosen UTF8 here)

        var inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);

            // Now decode it back

            MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("your string)` and write the resulting byte array to the stream.

Then, to decode the string use `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(your byte array)`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.write.aspx

```
// Create the data to write to the stream.
byte[] firstString = uniEncoding.GetBytes("Hello World");

using(var memStream = new MemoryStream(100))
{
  memStream.Write(firstString, 0 , firstString.Length);
}
```